# Rasterizing vector data for landscape permeability analysis

Tags: qgis, rasterization, landscape

So I vectorized an area with 12 different categories/features. My intention is to use this in the future for calculating landscape permeability. [image]

I would like to know which steps I need to take right now.
I presume it would be better to transform this into a raster, right? So I can give each pixel a value (in this case, 12 different values) and after that, continue with r.walk and so on.

If so, do I need to merge all these 12 files into one? Can I transform this into a raster while still keeping each of the different categories? (including the line vectors?)

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].